# iTunes keeps freezing every start on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, freeze, itunes

I recently did a fresh install of Windows 10.

Every time I start iTunes (I am on Version 12.2.2.25) it just displays a white screen and freezes.

If I start iTunes while pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> and select my iTunes.itl Library File manually, it starts without any problems. Changes are also saved to the database.

But the next time I open it without selecting the file manually, it freezes again.

I reinstalled it several times, tried an older Version (did not work, because of now incompatible library file), tried starting it as administrator or in compatibility mode for Win 8.1 and Win 7.

I can't find users with similar problems on the Internet.

Any ideas what to do?

Comment: How long did you wait for? If itunes shutdown incorrectly it can take a very long time to start as it checks your music library. Even after a normal shutdown it takes a minute or two to fully start on my laptop.

Comment: i once waited for maybe 10 minutes, but task manager also says: "inactive" next to the task. Before changing to Windows 10, it always started 2-3 seconds...